# Laravel Filament 3 Custom Page view props

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I have created a custom dashboard page and replaced it with main dashboard page. It loads perfectly. And the stats widget is also shown. But the problem is I can't pass props to the blade view. The static function view that I wrote doesn't actually exist in Page class. So it's not automatically executed. But `protected static string $view = 'filament.pages.dashboard';` is executed and the view page is displayed. But I want to pass user information and other datas to the blade page. I am using filament 3. And this is my dashboard Page snippet

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Pages;

use App\Filament\Widgets\OverviewWidget;
use App\Filament\Widgets\StatsOverview;

use Filament\Pages\Page;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class Dashboard extends Page
{
    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-home';

    protected static string $view = 'filament.pages.dashboard';

    protected function getHeaderWidgets(): array
    {
        return [
            StatsOverview::class,
        ];
    }

    // create a view
    public static function view(): View
    {
        $user = auth()->user(); // get the authenticated user
        Log::inf("Hello Earth");
        return view('filament.pages.dashboard', compact('user'));
    }

}
```

And this is my view blade page

```
<x-filament-panels::page>
    Hello {{ $user->name }}
</x-filament-panels::page>
```

It says the $user is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's part of livewire rather than filament.

You can pass data like below

```
public $user;

public function mount()
{
    $this->user = auth()->user();
}
```

Or If you want to display `auth()` data then you can simple display from blade file like `auth()->user()->name` without checking from component

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted; this is indeed how you pass data to a Livewire component's view.

Answer (score -1):

Overwrite the getViewData function from the BasePage class so that instead of returning an empty array it returns the data array you want to pass to the view. You don't need to overwrite the static view function at all:

```
protected function getViewData(): array
    {

        $user = auth()->user(); // get the authenticated user
        return compact('user');
    }
```